# Why does my code fail to pass the test of removing spaces from string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-parsing

Hi everyone! I'm new to coding and I'm failing to pass this test. I need to write my code in order for this string:

```
'<h2>         Lost In Space</h2>'
```

to be changed to this string (basically remove the extra spaces between the header and the text):

```
'<h2>Lost In Space</h2>'
```

The code I wrote looks like this and in my editor it seems to return the correct output but for some reason it fails when put through the online test

```
function markdownParser(markdown) {
    let arr = markdown.trim().split(' ');
    let firstItemInArray = arr[0]; 
    if(firstItemInArray[0] === '<') {
        arr.shift(); 
        let newString = arr.join(' '); 
        let trimmedString = newString.trim(); 
        return `${firstItemInArray}${trimmedString}`
      } else {
        return markdown;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening and where is my mistake?

Failing test:
edge_cases

```
expected '<h2>         Lost In Space</h2>' to deeply equal '<h2>Lost In Space</h2>'
```

Comment: please provide us the failing test cases

Comment: This specific example seems to pass, but maybe the online testing tool runs your snippet against a larger set of test data, and it doesn't handle some other edge case?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. I'm only getting the error:  edge_cases
expected '<h2>         Lost In Space</h2>' to deeply equal '<h2>Lost In Space</h2>'
Not sure how to pass this test

Comment: Can you put this failing example properly formatted in your question?

Comment: I just tried your "failing test", it does pass: `markdownParser('<h2>         Lost In Space</h2>') === '<h2>Lost In Space</h2>'` gives back `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of cheating and a bit of a hack, but a reliable one.  Could be changed to only trim the text nodes.  Name implies it's Markdown, so this might not actually work?

```js
str=`<h2>     test</h2>`

const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML=str
div.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(x=>x.innerHTML=x.innerHTML.trim())

console.log(div.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```